# Command line option to disable an execution in maven?

Tags: maven

The Spark pom.xml has the following set of executions:  in particular I am interested in the "attach-scaladocs" one at the bottom of this snippet:

```
        <execution>
          <id>attach-scaladocs</id>
          <phase>verify</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>doc-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
```

Here is the larger environment in which the snippet lives:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>scala-compile-first</id>
          <phase>process-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>scala-test-compile-first</id>
          <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-scaladocs</id>
          <phase>verify</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>doc-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
```

That particular execution is time consuming and unnecessary for my needs. However, it is not in my best interest to modify the pom.xml (by commenting it out - which works fine BTW) due to git merge issues.

Any way to disable that execution via a maven command line switch?

Comment: If it is just the git merge issues that bother you, you can try to modify the file and use git assume unchange

Comment: @xi.lin  Does "assume unchanged" allow later git updates to that file when fetch from remote repo?

Comment: Yes, it will show a conflict that need you resolve. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree